# which is the correct way to insert data with subquery inside using ef core

Tags: c#, api, repository

I have a .net API using EF Core with the following entities [following entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8R8F.png)

My goal is to send an `User` `id` to the API and based on this `id` the application should retrieve the `name` from the `User` table and insert it on the `Name` table

`UserRepository.cs`

```
public int GetNameById(int userId)
{
    var result = _context.User.Where(u => u.Id == userId).Select(u => new { u.Name }).FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

`NameRepository.cs`

```
    public void AddName(Name name)
    {
        _context.Name.Add(name);
    } 
// _context.SaveChanges() later
```

In the controller is where I call their respective services and they call their respective repositories.
I made the search and the insert separately so I can reuse these method in the future. EF core is generating two queries, I wanted it all in single one for performance reasons, how can I do it? They already share the same context

In short I want methods that can be reusable and run all in one query.
(On my real project the entities are totally different, I changed it so it would be easier to understand my issue)

Answer (score 0):

1. method should return a `string` value, not `int`, i guess:

```
public string GetNameById(int id)
{
  return dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id)?.Name;
}
```

2. according your model:

   ```
   var name = new Name { Name = "New name" };
   name.Id = 0;
   ```

if Name.Id is IDENTITY column, then comment Id assignment
otherwise use some value
...

```
public void AddName(Name name)
{
  dbContext.Names.Add(name);
}
// dbContext.SaveChanges(); somewhere
```